# Can I Define The buildscript repositories In The Root Project For All Modules

Tags: gradle

I have code similar to the following in each of my sub-modules but with different plugins

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```

Can the repositories be set in the root project so I don't repeat it?

I already have the main repositories section set in the root like this but this question is for the plugins and the `buildscript` section.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `buildscript` block can't be put into a separate file and then imported, it's a special one.

What you can do on the other hand is to put your `buildscript` block into the `build.gradle` file of the root project and then all other build files from subprojects will inherit this block.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the repositories from the `buildscript` of the root project, like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories.addAll rootProject.buildscript.repositories
    // plugin dependencies, etc, go here
}
```

You still have to copy that one line to the `buildscript` block of your subsidiary Gradle file, but at least it is just one line. This works both for subprojects, and also for additional `.gradle` files you include using `apply from:`

You can even put that one-liner into a method in `build.gradle`:

```
rootProject.ext.setupPluginRepos = {
    it.repositories.addAll rootProject.buildscript.repositories
}
```

So then your subproject (or Gradle file) just has to do this:

```
buildscript {
    rootProject.ext.setupPluginRepos(it)
    // plugin dependencies, etc, go here
}
```

I wrote a custom Gradle plugin, used for certain internal projects at my employer. It adds an extension to every project, let us just call it `xyzzy` (not its actual name). So I added the above `setupPluginRepos` to my plugin, and now I just have to do:

```
buildscript {
    xyzzy.setupPluginRepos(it)
    // plugin dependencies, etc, go here
}
```