# How to import external gradle script file with plugins imported correctly in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, package

I encountered a plugin importing error when applying from an external Gradle script file.
For example: 
In file **gradle/lambda.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'jp.classmethod.aws.lambda'

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvocationType;

import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaDeleteFunctionTask;
import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaInvokeTask;
import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaMigrateFunctionTask;
import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaPublishVersionTask;
import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaCreateAliasTask;
import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaUpdateAliasTask;

import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.VpcConfigWrapper

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.38"
    }
}
```

In **build.gradle** file I apply the external script by this method:

```
apply from: 'gradle/lambda.gradle'
```

But it will produce an error about the plugin imports:

```
Plugin with id 'jp.classmethod.aws.lambda' not found.
```

It can be resolved by including the same buildscript code block in **build.gradle** file.

What's the root cause of this issue?
What's the recommended way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49551785/2003986), you should do this :

> What you can do on the other hand is to put your `buildscript` block
>   into the `build.gradle` file of the root project and then all other
>   build files from subprojects will inherit this block.

edit : it won't work due to the import. `classpath "jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.38"` is needed in `gradle/lambda.gradle` for the resolving the `import`, it's also needed in `build.gradle` as the plugin `jp.classmethod.aws.lambda` is apply from here (through the `apply from`)

Comment: Actually, it's not in the situation of multi-projects or subprojects. I'm trying to split the build.gradle file into different files in order to improve the modularity. And I've tried to remove the duplicated buildscript block from the one of the gradle file (build.gradle file & lambda.gradle), it will fail the compile.

Comment: Just add the buildscript in the top level build.gradle, centralize all dependencies here

Comment: not working well with the buildscript in the top level build.gradle only. `Cause: startup failed:
script '/Users/peixu/workspace/web-crawler/gradle/lambda.gradle': 14: unable to resolve class jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.VpcConfigWrapper
 @ line 14, column 1.
   import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.VpcConfigWrapper
   ^

script '/Users/peixu/workspace/web-crawler/gradle/lambda.gradle': 8: unable to resolve class jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaInvokeTask
 @ line 8, column 1.
   import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.lambda.AWSLambdaInvokeTask;`

Comment: I guess it's due to the `import`, the top level `buildscript` only works for `apply plugin`

Comment: Exactly due to import. Do you know how to resolve the issue of import?

Comment: As i said in my edit, i don't think there is a solution